# Is there a way to view RingCentral App (formerly Glip) video call statistics using the RingCentral APIs?

Tags: ringcentral, glip

I'm wondering if anybody has had success in viewing statistics about video calls in the RingCentral App.

For instance, the RingCentral API has lots of endpoints regarding posts, so I can see at a glance how many posts there were in my organization on a given day.  There are also call logs available, so I can see those.  But when it comes to video calls, either in the regular API or the compliance reports, I don't see any activity whatsoever. (https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Getting-Started)

This seems like a pretty large oversight, that the information about video calls are completely unavailable.  Unless I'm just not seeing them.  Has anybody had any success?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way to get video call / meeting statistics via the API. The team is aware of this and seeing what can be done. Until then, use the RingCentral Analytics Portal's Meetings Dashboard can be used for some info:

- Analytics Portal Overview - Website

  - https://www.ringcentral.com/office/features/analytics-portal/overview.html
- Analytics Portal Overview - Knowledgebase article

  - https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/10143-Analytics-Portal-Overview-RingCentral